# Timing how long it takes to get an input python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm kind of new to python and writing a simple program.

What it does is it prints out a random eight digit number. The user then enters that same number, and the program then checks the input to see if it matches the random number. This all works great, the problem is with what I would like to do next, that is time how long it takes for the user to input his number.

So it would time from the moment it printed its number till the user entered his.

can someone help thanks...?

Comment: i kinds stumbled over time.time() my question is more about how to have the program stop the timer when there is an input?

Comment: once I looked more carefully at what you posted John, I realized it was exactly what I needed, I was forgetting that the program flow would stop until there was an input. So as long as the input is between the start and end, it works great...thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) for this:

```
start = time.time()
# do stuff
end = time.time()
print("it took", (end-start), "seconds")
```